# How to add request body when post a image in Qt?

Tags: qt, http, post

I am confusing when I want to post a image file to server. With a clear post, I can just use QHttpMultiPart ,and it works fine. But this time I want to add some params, the server just don't get them.

I have searched for days , But no solution is found.
The code goes like this:

```
QUrl url("http://192.168.1.211/v1");
QUrlQuery query;
//following params are  what i want to add
query.addQueryItem("app_name", "pc");
query.addQueryItem("ip", "192.168.1.110");
query.addQueryItem("dev_os","android");
query.addQueryItem("dev_os_ver","11.4.1");
query.addQueryItem("dev_model",testEquip);
query.addQueryItem("latitude","23.137466");
query.addQueryItem("longitude","113.352425");
query.addQueryItem("user_id","1");
query.addQueryItem("nickname","nick");
query.addQueryItem("sex","1");
query.addQueryItem("headimgurl","http://some.com/");
url.setQuery(query);

QNetworkRequest req;
req.setUrl(url);
req.setRawHeader("X-Api-Key","JDZBNH3HDFI823AISDU9SF32IRJ");

QHttpMultiPart *multiPart=new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
QHttpPart imagePart;
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpeg"));
imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,QVariant("form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\""+filename+"\""));
QFile *file=new QFile(path);
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
imagePart.setBodyDevice(file);
file->setParent(multiPart);
multiPart->append(imagePart);

QNetworkAccessManager *manager=new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkReply *reply=manager->post(req,multiPart);
multiPart->setParent(reply);
```

The response code shows no params have been accessed. So what is the right way to add these params?

Comment: Are you sure these parameters should be in `QUrl` and not in another `QHttpPart`?

Comment: @Sergei Ousynin  I actually don't  where to put them. I have tried what you said , but I'm not sure  I was doing it right. Could you give me a example or something?

Comment: Don't know about multipart requests, but I used to post requests to SalesForce with code like this https://i.imgur.com/blyRQLl.png

Comment: @Sergei Ousynin tried that already. And I convert image file to byte ,add it to QUrl together. But it didn't work.